# is there a bug in pandas DataFrame corrwith function?

Tags: pandas, correlation

Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000), columns=['a'])
frame2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000)**2, columns=['a'])
c1 = frame1.corrwith(frame2) #  0.968185
c2=np.corrcoef(frame1['a'],frame2['a'])[0][1] # 0.96818535723302579
```

this seems ok, **but**

```
frame1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10000), columns=['a'])
frame2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10000)**2, columns=['a'])
c1 = frame1.corrwith(frame2) #  2.31913 ???????
c2=np.corrcoef(frame1['a'],frame2['a'])[0][1] # 0.96823978537480138
```

So, why is c1 larger than 1 (which is of course an impossible correlation value)?

**Update after seeing the comments**

I was using an old version (0.10), after upgrading to version 0.13.0rc1 the problem has been solved.

Comment: seems ok on 0.12 and 0.13rc1...what version are you on?

Comment: pd.version.version returns 0.10.0, perhaps it's time to upgrade

Comment: @Jeff: for stuff like this, is it worth adding a test to make sure it stays fixed, whatever the reason was?  I can't find any (explicit) reference to `corrcoef` in tests.

Comment: sure....these can always use tests (esp as this is an actual calculation).

Comment: Will submit PR, then.

Comment: ok, I can confirm that after upgrading to 0.13.0rc1 it works

Comment: @Mannaggia: thanks for the report -- your example has now been merged into the pandas test suite, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/test_frame.py#L6466)!